# Which is the best way to deactivate an user account with ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, devise

I have a big problem and would like your help, with an option to disable a user account with multiple dependencies.

I believe that there is no magic to it, but let's see what can be done:

I have a model called `User::Account` with all dependencies (has_manies, has_ones...), but these dependencies are used throughout the system and everything works well only with the existence or absence of these records. There is nothing to define when these dependencies are active or inactive.

But I need that when the model `User::Account` is defined as inactive (through a column in DB for example), all these dependencies are also disabled, as if they didn't exists, so I don't have to change the entire operation of the system. Or a less painful way to make it happen.

Suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing more specifics it's hard to give exact advice,
but I'd suggest you're probably looking for a `before_filter`.

Something of this sort.

```
class ApplicationController

  private

  def user_must_be_active!
    if !@user.active?
      flash[:error] = "User Account is not active"
      redirect_to user_profile_path
    end
  end

end
```

Thereby in any controller that a user must be active for we can say

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :user_must_be_active!
end
```

Or perhaps there are just some actions we care about

```
class SomeOtherController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :user_must_be_active!, :only => :some_action
end
```

Comment: I understand the possibility of checks throughout the system, making sure the parent of dependency exists to display it or not, etc.. But is there an easier way?

Comment: i suggest you update your question with what you think might work, and we can advise a better way. my solution is about controller level permissions for a user. If you were trying to get "all posts for active users" on a model level my answer would be different.